# Launch JADE Agents from an Agent into another Container

Tags: pug, agents-jade, agents

So i have developed a multiagent system that is comprised of some administration agents and some control agents. I have a inprocess launcher of the JADE platform where I create two new non-main containers (one for admin agents and the other for control agents). The admin agents setup a simulation process and then start the simulation. the control agents provide parameters to the simulation model. each simulation project can be different meaning different control agents are required and must be launched after the admin agents have negotiated the configuration.

I launch the agents from one of my administration agents, but as my admin agent is located in the admin container, the control agents are launched there too! (I can only grab the residing containerController of the admin agent)is it possible for me to launch the control agents directly into the control container?

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with a work around solution. The control agents that I launch from the admin agent will be passed a ContainerID object as an argument which represents the address of the control container. the control agents are then launched in the same container as the admin agents.

In the setup of the ControlAgent one can use the doMove() method to shift from one container to another. an object that uses the Location interface is required for doMove(), which according to the [API  v4.4.0](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/core/Location.html) , ContainerID implements.

I will try this later this week and post up the outcome.